# Use Gradle to compile SpringSource,Error:Unable to make the module:xxx-xxx,related gradle configuration was not found

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle

I clone the source code of Spring from GitHub, then import into IDEA

I created a new module(spring-roberto) to make a test, when i run Junit Test there is a mistake

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JcO7.png)
I try to refresh gradle module,but it seem to doesn't solve my problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNVdU.png)

code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgvCy.png)
My English is poor,But I have tried to describe clearly my problem, I hope you can understand.